# How to pass parameters between an index form and a new form in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that shows me a list of 'challenges' each challenge can have many entries. I would like a user to be able to create an 'entry' so that the entry has the id of the parent challenge.

I am having difficulty passing the id of the parent challenge to the foreign key challenge_id of entry in the new form

Fields of challenge table are

```
id :integer
rule :string
```

Fields of the entry table are

```
id :integer
challenge_id :integer
Title :string
```

The views I have are:

challenges/_index

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pointsspend</th>
      <th>Rules</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @challenges.each do |challenge| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= challenge.pointsSpend %></td>
        <td><%= challenge.rules %></td>
        <td><%= challenge.id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to image_tag("list.jpg"), entries_path, {:class => "AllEntryLink", :"data-challenge_id" => challenge.id}  %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    <td><div class="inline AllEntries" data-challenge_id="<%= challenge.id %>"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

entries/_index

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <td><%= link_to image_tag("add.jpg"), new_entry_path, id: "NewEntryLink" %> 
    <% @entries.each do |entry| %>
        <%= entry.blob %>
        <%= image_tag entry.picture.url if entry.picture? %>
    <% end %></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<script>
</script>
```

the entries/new form

```
<%= form_for(@entry, html: { multipart: true })  do |f| %>
  <% if @entry.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@entry.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this entry from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @entry.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :blob %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :blob %>
    <%= f.file_field :picture %>

  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The controllers

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_entry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])
    @entries = Entry.where(:challenge_id => @challenge.id)
    render :layout => false
  end


  # GET /entries/new
  def new
    @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:id])
    @entry = Entry.new
    @entry.challenge_id = @challenge.id
  end

  def create
  @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:id])
  @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)
  @entry.challenge_id = @challenge.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @entry }

      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

      end
    end
  end

  def entry_params
  params.require(:entry).permit(:id, :blob, :challenge_id, :picture)
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_entry
      @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def entry_params
      params.require(:entry).permit(:blob)
    end
end
```

routes

```
get '/entries/new/:challenge_id', to: 'entries#new'
resources :challenges, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index, :edit, :destroy]
```

Comment: what is the part that not work i can see that you use `@challenge.id` in create method of entry ?

Comment: the challenge_id column for an entry is nil so that the id of the parent challenge is not being passed to the new entry form

Comment: The id column in the challenge table is just called id so should I change the line here @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])  so that :challenge_id is just :id

Comment: if the user want to add new entry he has to select the parent (Challenge) first ? have you already an select or an list of `Challenges` in new entry form ?

Comment: Yes he selects the parent Challenge first. The list of challenges is on the challenges/_index form. When a user clicks a challenge, ajax is triggered to render the _index of associated entries (in s horizontal line of entries) at the beginning of this entry line is a further 'add new entry' button which triggers the new entry form

Comment: Can you add please the form of new entry to the question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83808/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-sebastian-zeki).